# C# How to start list count on 0

Tags: c#, arrays, list, foreach, count

I have a list that I want to print out and want the count to start counting on 0 and not 1. Here's the code block.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (string[] element in logBook) {
   count++;
   Console.WriteLine ("#{0}: {1}", count, element[0]);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What does this code do that is different from what you expect it to?

Comment: Why arent you using a for look instead?

Comment: You should increment after writing to console. This is saying "increase counter, then print to screen" so it will start printing with 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your counter incrementing in the wrong place.

```
int count = 0;

foreach (string[] element in logBook) {

   Console.WriteLine ("#{0}: {1}", count, element[0]);
   count++;   // Increment after you print
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can increment the count in a different way...that's the cool thing about the increment operator.

```
int count = 0;

foreach(string[] element in logBook) {

    Console.WriteLine ("#{0}: {1}", count++, element[0]);
}
```